# Replace a system lib

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

Generally speaking, is it possible to compile a custom version of a system library (say `libsurfaceflinger.so`), copy it to my Android device, reboot and expect it to work?

I'm just brainstorming about creating an app that would do this. The obvious problem would be binary incompatibility, ie. if I compile the lib against AOSP 4.4, it probably won't work on AOSP 2.3 devices. Other than that, are there any obstacles to this approach?

Edit: the hypothetical app would require root of course.

Comment: The system libs tend to use private APIs heavily, and these APIs often change between releases.  Sometimes the libs are modified by OEMs for specific devices.  You really can't mix & match something like libsurfaceflinger across different devices.

Comment: Isn't everything in, let's say libsurfaceflinger, a private API? I was thinking about targeting a specific device at first (e.g. Moto G) and then evaluate whether generalizing to more devices would be possible.

Comment: Basic collections like Vector can have methods added / removed / updated, so your libsurfaceflinger needs to exactly match libutils.  surfaceflinger's behavior has evolved over time, and other parts of the system rely on it behaving a certain way.  Sometimes common code moves from one library to another, so if you only replace one lib you could end up with two copies of something, or zero copies.  So there's multiple reasons why dropping in a new libsurfaceflinger can break, and it doesn't always fail with a nice "here's what you did wrong" in the log file. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another very important problem is that, unless you've rooted your device, you won't be able to replace a system library.

A possible work around to this problem (depending on the library it won't work, e.g. libcore that is used from System.loadLibrary) would be changing library's name and loading this library directly from your application (by using System.loadLibrary or `dlopen` from native source code). But, as I said, I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: Thanks, in this case I want to change the bahavior of the system, not of one app only, so rename won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I have tried a similar thing in a device (with custom rom) and it worked as expected. But it doesn't work every time. I have a success ratio of 2:3. (2 times it worked)